# Cannot properly form xaml for command binding

Tags: wpf, vb.net

I'm trying to implement command binding so that my user can use Alt+ for navigation.  I found [this](http://www.java2s.com/Tutorial/VB/0290__Windows-Presentation-Foundation/CustomCommandbyKeyGestureandRoutedUICommand.htm) example but am having problems forming the xmlns and the CommandBinding xaml.

This is what I have so far.  I know it's not formed correctly.

```
    xmlns:local="clr-namespace:xxxxx"

<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding
        Command="{x:Static local:xxxxx.ProjectMsg}"
        Executed="ProjectMsg"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

The coding for the command is here in the MainWindow vb:

```
Class MainWindow


Public Shared ProjectTab_AltP As New RoutedCommand


Public Sub New()

    ' This call is required by the designer.
    InitializeComponent()

    ' Add any initialization after the InitializeComponent() call.

End Sub

Private Sub MainWindow_Loaded(sender As Object, e As RoutedEventArgs) Handles Me.Loaded


    ProjectTab_AltP.InputGestures.Add(New KeyGesture(Key.P, ModifierKeys.Control))
    Me.CommandBindings.Add(New CommandBinding(ProjectTab_AltP, AddressOf Me.ProjectMsg))

End Sub

Private Sub ProjectMsg(sender As Object, e As ExecutedRoutedEventArgs)

    MessageBox.Show("hi")

End Sub
```

I get an error that the name "xxxxx" does not exist in the namespace clr-namespace:xxxxx.

In the main window vb, there is not a namespace declared.  Numerous errors occur if I attempt to add one.

Do I have to have a namespace in the main window vb?

I'm a noob at wpf so I would appreciate any help or advice.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Do I have to have a namespace in the main window vb?

No. Check what the root namespace of your application is under Project->Properties->Application->Root namespace in Visual Studio. It is the same as the name of your application by default, for example "WpfApplication1":

```
xmlns:local="clr-namespace:WpfApplication1"
```

You should also expose the command through a *property*:

```
Public Shared ReadOnly Property ProjectTab_AltP() As RoutedUICommand = New RoutedUICommand()
```

---

```
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <CommandBinding
    Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ProjectTab_AltP}"
    Executed="ProjectMsg"/>
</Window.CommandBindings>
```

Answer (score 0):

`local` is an alias for VB namespace `xxxxx`. Is `xxxxx` contained within `xxxxx`? No. It is not contained within itself. `local:xxxxx` could at most mean something like `xxxxx.xxxxx`, except that you can't put namespaces there.

The right way to bind to a static command property is like this:

```
Command="{x:Static local:WhateverClassName.StaticCommandProperty}"
```

What's a static command property?

It's a static property that returns a command. A command is any object that implements the interface `System.Windows.Input.ICommand`. `ProjectMsg` isn't that. It's a method.

See mm8's excellent answer for how to solve your problem by that route.

Below is a more pure-XAML way to do it.

I think the command binding you're creating in `MainWindow_Loaded` is OK as it is, but try commenting that stuff out and doing this in your XAML. The *only* thing in your VB that this uses is your `ProjectMsg()` execute handler method.

```
<Window.Resources>
    <!-- Create a command object. -->
    <RoutedUICommand
        x:Key="ProjectMsgCmdResource"
        />
</Window.Resources>
<Window.CommandBindings>
    <!-- Bind the command object to your command execute method. -->
    <CommandBinding
        Command="{StaticResource ProjectMsgCmdResource}"
        Executed="ProjectMsg"
        />
</Window.CommandBindings>
<Window.InputBindings>
    <!-- And bind a key input binding to your command. -->
    <KeyBinding
        Key="P"
        Modifiers="Ctrl"
        Command="{StaticResource ProjectMsgCmdResource}"
        />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

Comment: The root namespace is "xxxxx" according to the project properties.  I can't seem to get the ProjectTab_AltP property in the correct place in the vb coding without getting errors.  Where exactly does it go?  I've put it under "Class MainWindow" and in a class by itself but get errors that the property is not accessible, "xxxxx" doesn't exist in "xxxxx". or that expanded properties cannot be initialized.  Thanks

Comment: @EManning I explained that in my answer. If you're unable to understand, just copy what mm8 has. He showed you exactly what to do. Just copy and paste this XAML from his answer: `Command="{x:Static local:MainWindow.ProjectTab_AltP}"`.

Comment: I discovered that I had a "()" at the end of one of the command binding statements.  The alt+P worked fine after removing them.  I kept the "Public Shared ProjectTab_AltP..." the same.  If it really should be changed to a property then my question above still applies.    Thanks to you both for your help.